DTIME(t(n) logt(n)) relation to DTIME(t(n)) / sublin
I need some homework help and I'm not sure how to solve it. We have to show that DTIME($t(n) \text{ log } t(n)) \nsubseteq DTIME(t(n))/$sublin for every time-constructible $t(n)$.
Sublin is the class of all advice functions $h$ where $h(n) \leq n - 1$.
I'm not familiar with advice beyond poly. Obviously DTIME($t(n) \text{ log } t(n)) \nsubseteq DTIME(t(n))$ since loglinear is greater than linear, and from the question, even with the advice, it still won't be right. I presume it can be solved by proving a contradiction that DTIME($t(n) \text{ log } t(n)) \subseteq DTIME(t(n))/$sublin is false.
How do I solve it?
